# insert or update data to MySQL server through an internet or mobile data

Tags: mysql, reactjs, react-native

First foremost I'm totally new to this knowledge about send the data to MySQL server through an internet connection or mobile data. Actually I'm working with a job tracking app where it will store all the job detail when the employee insert, including the start and end time. I use react native to implement this apps for IOS user. Basically for now the all the function are works perfectly, but the limitation is the data will store in the MySQL server ONLY if the user is connected to the local network. So is there any ways for insert the data to the server if the user connect with other internet connection or using mobile data. The MySQL server is setup in a NAS with ip: 192.16x.x.xxx so I have created some API inside the Web folder of the NAS to fetch the data, which in the react native code I have implemented an FETCH function which will fetch the api exp:`http://192.16x.x.xxx/api/insert.php` and lastly the network public ip is 175.xxx.x.x.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can insert update etc.you Can do with other internet connection (WAN)

Comment: appreciate if you can explain more about it

Comment: Is your database server located remote server. If yes than you can easily make api for insert ,update delete and read. You can setup server to serve data with any IP address,

Comment: what if my MySQL database did not locate on lo located remote server

Comment: mean your mysql database located on live server like any vps, hostinger etc. than          you can do CRUD opration throgh out api

Comment: yes it only can do the crud operation when the device is connecting to the local network how about when it is using mobile data or other internet connection? and also the mysql database is setup inside a NAS

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: when you'r using NAS than it's not possiable to do that because NAS always run on Local network. you should be use live server(Hostinger ) to do that.

Comment: Your Database Server should have a public IP address, or it's IP should be accessible through public by port forwarding. Also, the database access by remote needs to be enabled. you can send and retrieve data by the API if you want to work the database with local connection. configure this port forwarding on your router. 175.X.X.X:### 192.168.X.X:###. The ### is the port configured in your database and app setting.